# Applying Formatter to logrus global logger

Tags: go

Disclaimer: I've been working with go for... about a day. I'm a genuine n00b here...

I want to have a logrus logger that's configured with default fields in main(), so I don't have to count on other devs always logging the required fields every time. As a prototype, I have this, which works exactly as I want:

```
package main
import (
 "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)
var (
 log    *logrus.Logger
 logger *logrus.Entry
)
func foo(x, y string) {
 logger.WithFields(logrus.Fields{"A": x, "B": y}).Error("error!")
}
func main() {
 x := "argle"
 y := "bargle"
 log = logrus.New()
 logger = logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{"X": x, "Y": y})
//  log.Formatter = &logrus.JSONFormatter{}
 logger.Info("Info!")
 logger.Debug("Debug!")
 foo("xyzzy", "fnord")
}
```

The problem is the Formatter. I cannot for the life of me figure out the magical incantation to get a Formatter applied to `logger`. If I uncomment it as is, JSON formatting is not applied. If I write it as

`logger.Formatter = &logrus.JSONFormatter{}`

I get

> ./foo.go:17:8: logger.Formatter undefined (type *logrus.Entry has no field or method Formatter)

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: use logrus.SetFormatter()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{})` to change `logrus` format to JSON. Here is the working code of your with a few changes.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

var (
    log    *logrus.Logger
    logger *logrus.Entry
)

func foo(x, y string) {
    logger.WithFields(logrus.Fields{"A": x, "B": y}).Error("error!")
}

func main() {
    x := "argle"
    y := "bargle"

    log = logrus.New()

    log.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{})

    logger = log.WithFields(logrus.Fields{"X": x, "Y": y})

    logger.Info("Info!")
    logger.Debug("Debug!")
    foo("xyzzy", "fnord")
}
```

One can also set `logrus` format to text by using

```
logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.TextFormatter{})
```

Feel free to play around with the code on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vnYeOU4yAsr).